# How to use RegEx to find strings deep inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, discord.js

I'm currently trying to find a way to match user input to find a user in Discord, for commands that we didn't necessarily want tagging the user. As it is, the method I'm using to get that username is

```
var member = message.guild.members.find('nickname', `${searched}`);
```

However this only pulls the name if it's an exact match, which is kind of annoying.
How would I go about pulling a name with only a partial bit of it?

For further clarification, the variable 'searched' is what I'm looking to replace in order to match the string provided by user input to the nickname attribute in Discord's members objects.

EDIT
Found what I was looking for

```
var member = message.guild.members.find(element => element.nickname.includes(searched) == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if `members` is an array. It should match `nickname` anywhere in the string.

```js
const nickRegx = new RegExp('nickname')
var member = message.guild.members.find((member => nickRegx.test(member));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question after an hour or so

```
var member = message.guild.members.find(element => element.nickname.includes(searched) == true);
```